# UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification called multiple times with a small change in accelerometer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation, nsnotificationcenter

I am using

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(detectOrientation) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```

to make changes to some views in my appdelegate.

But this gets called in a slightest variation of the accelerometer. Can anyone suggest any workaround, so that it gets only called when the device is completely rotated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you write some code to check the device's width = 480 and height = 320 (this is when the device has been rotated 90 degrees) before posting the notification?

So something like:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

...

if(width == 480 && height == 320)
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification . . . ];
}
```

Comment: Not sure how this would work since it would just post it twice. This check should be in the selector for the notification.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
     //your code here
}
```

override this method in your view controller. It will get called when the device has rotated to a new orientation

Comment: I have specified in my question, that i am using it in my appdelegate. Unfortunately this doesn't work because it is not a UIViewController

Comment: What sort of changes to views are you trying to make? There is not such thing as UIViews without UIViewControllers.

Comment: This code works only inside viewcontrollers. Not in appdelegate;